# Flutter use variable created inside Future builder outside of the build method,

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have a future builder witch i use to fetch data, i need to use what i get from the api to a text editing controller that has to be defined outside of build and i need to give the text editing controller an initial value, in this initial value i need to put data3.firstName and data3.lastName, for now the initial values are hardcoded.

```
Future<Response> fetchAccountData() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String? authorization = prefs.getString('authorization');
  var url = 'https://dev.api.wurk.skyver.co/api/v1/employees/account';

  response1 = await http.get(
    Uri.parse(url),
    headers: <String, String>{
      'authorization': authorization ?? basicAuth.toString()
    },
  );

  return response1;
}

factory AccountData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return AccountData(
        firstName: json['firstName'],
        lastName: json['lastName'],
        phoneNumber: json['phoneNumber']);
  }
}

Future<void> putAccountData() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String? authorization = prefs.getString('authorization');
    var url = 'https://dev.api.wurk.skyver.co/api/v1/employees/account';
    Map payload = {
      "firstName": editedFirstName.text,
      "lastName": editedLastName.text,
    };
    try {
      final response = await http.put(Uri.parse(url),
          headers: <String, String>{
            'authorization': authorization ?? basicAuth.toString(),
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
          body: jsonEncode(payload));
    } catch (er) {}
  }

TextEditingController editedFirstName =
  TextEditingController(text: 'firstName'); << needs to be data3.firstName
  TextEditingController editedLastName =
  TextEditingController(text: 'lastName');<< needs to be data3.lastName

return SafeArea(
      child: WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => const ProfileScreen(),
            ),
          );
          return shouldPop;
        },

body: FutureBuilder<Response>(
                  future: futureData,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      AccountData data3 = AccountData.fromJson( << data3 has data3.firstName, and 
                                                                                   data3.lastName
                        json.decode(snapshot.data!.body),
                      );
```

Comment: I'd say "learn Riverpod".  Trivial to code stuff like that.  It's like Lego for Dart/Flutter.

Comment: Yeah i need to get on it, seems like most of the problems i go through are easily fixed with state managment

Comment: Please add your code for `fetchAccountData`

Comment: @Josteve ok no problem

Comment: Hey @Ajan, is it possible you share your full code (Request and Ui) in paste bin?

Comment: @Josteve sure here https://pastebin.com/x1UXzAdL

Comment: is there any extra info you would need

Answer (score 4):

I don't fully understand the reason to have a global TextController (and I don't think its a good idea either) but using Riverpod it would look somethink like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

class AccountData {
  final String firstName;
  final String lastName;
  final String phoneNumber;
  
  AccountData({
    required this.firstName,
    required this.lastName,
    required this.phoneNumber,
  });
  
  factory AccountData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return AccountData(
      firstName: json['firstName'],
      lastName: json['lastName'],
      phoneNumber: json['phoneNumber'],
    );
  }
}

Future<Map<String, dynamic>> fetchAccountData() async {
  final response = {
    'firstName': 'Name',
    'lastName': 'LastName',
    'phoneNumber': '98786758690',
  };
  return Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () => response);
}

final futureData = FutureProvider<AccountData>((_) async {
  final data = await fetchAccountData();
  return AccountData.fromJson(data);
});
  
final firstNameController = ChangeNotifierProvider<TextEditingController>((ref) {
  final controller = TextEditingController();
  ref.listen<AsyncValue<AccountData>>(futureData, (_, curr) {
    curr.whenOrNull(
      data: (d) => controller.text = d.firstName,
    );
  });
  
  return controller;
});

final lastNameController = ChangeNotifierProvider<TextEditingController>((ref) {
  final controller = TextEditingController();
  ref.listen<AsyncValue<AccountData>>(futureData, (_, curr) {
    curr.whenOrNull(
      data: (d) => controller.text = d.lastName,
    );
  });
  
  return controller;
});

void main() {
  runApp(const ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp();
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends ConsumerWidget {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final firstController = ref.watch(firstNameController.notifier);
    final lastcontroller = ref.watch(lastNameController.notifier);
    return ref.watch(futureData).when(
      loading: () => const CircularProgressIndicator(),
      error: (e, _) => TextButton(
        child: Text('$e'),
        onPressed: () => ref.refresh(futureData),
      ),
      data: (_) {
        return Column(
          children: [
            TextField(
              controller: firstController,
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: lastcontroller,
            ),
          ]
        );
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Now following [Hazar Belge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16766831/hazar-belge) using a late initializer is a good idea, without state managament the idea would be simply use a FutureBuilder and then pass down the data to an StatefulWidget which initialize the TextEditingControllers with that data, and again using didUpdateWidget, all of it without depending of an external package (the bigger your app you would need to use more packages to help you develop fast but I would recommend try with the basic to grasp all you can do with the framework)

Comment: yup i fixed it without really using state management but i really appreciate you posting the answer about riverpod because im trying to learn it, so im defo gonna use your answer as help on a different place so thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use late initialization like this:

```
late TextEditingController editedFirstName;
late TextEditingController editedLastName;

return SafeArea(
   child: WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
         Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => const ProfileScreen(),
            ),
         );
         return shouldPop;
      },

body: FutureBuilder<Response>(
         future: futureData,
         builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
               AccountData data3 = AccountData.fromJson( << data3 has data3.firstName, and 
                                                                                   data3.lastName
                json.decode(snapshot.data!.body),
               );
               editedFirstName = TextEditingController(text: data3.firstname)
               editedLastName = TextEditingController(text: data3.lastname)
```

Comment: Sorry, but it doesnt work. The only way to make it work is to give the initial value outside build, so if you know an answer that would give data3.firstName as initial text outside build it would make it work, if i try give a hardcoded text outside of the build method it works

Comment: It probably doesn't work because of the widget where you use these controllers. If you can share both complete stateless widget and error, I/We can help you more easily.

Comment: full code here, https://pastebin.com/EHZbdT50

Comment: and i have a stateful widget

Comment: and there is no error really, all i need is to use data3.firstName and lastName outside build

Comment: I ran this script and it's working fine:
https://pastebin.com/1wuHTgBA I don't know another solution without state managements. So you can review it again maybe you can find anything.

Comment: yeah i reviewed it and it seemed to work on your solution but it wasnt working on mine, do you know a good way of doing this using state managment, i would really appreciate it

Comment: @Ajan Define a two late textEditingController and then call your future method inside the initState method but don't await it, do with .then and catch. Then while loading show a progress indicator and then once you got the value from API and your widget builds the widget tree completely (check with WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback), then initialize your text editing controller with the initial value and call setState method and in the build method show the text field widget

Comment: oh okay i see, but do you mind doing like an answer with it and the code so i understand well, and also understand the (WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback), part, i would really appreciate it

Comment: @Ajan I don't know whether you're looking like this one. But anyway, can you try this code in dartpad.dev, https://pastebin.com/raw/w4nciSB1 and let me know if you're still looking for a solution

Comment: @VinothVino thank you for trying to help me but i dont think it fixes what im trying to do, im simply trying to use data3.firstName and data3.lastName to the text editing controllers declared globaly, that would fix the problem, having this>> editedFirstName = TextEditingController(text: data3.firstName);

and the variable needs to be global, declared and assigned in order to fix my problem, because if i just add to it a hardcoded string it all works fine so i just need to pass data.firstName to the global text editing controller and ill be good